# How to set image into canvas and get proper coordinates on click

Tags: angular, canvas, html5-canvas, coordinates, offset

I'm try to set different devices(iphone 7,XR,ipad mini) screenshot into canvas and get coordinates when u click on any part of the screenshot.
But due to the height,width is different for different device I'm not able to fetch coordinates.Somehow for phones I'm getting proper coordinates but its not working for tablets.I tried different things nothing worked as I'm new to canvas don't have much idea..please help .TIA.

My HTML code -

```
<canvas id="canvas" (click)="getOffset($event)" width="500" height="650"
    style="cursor: pointer;margin-top: 1em;"></canvas>
```

Mt TS code to draw canvas-

```
let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let imageObj = new Image();
  let wrh = this.screenData.imageWidth / this.screenData.imageHeight;
  let newWidth = canvas.width;
  let newHeight = newWidth / wrh;
  if (newHeight > canvas.height) {
      newHeight = canvas.height;
      newWidth = newWidth * wrh;
  }  
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0,newWidth,newHeight);
  };
  imageObj.src =  'data:image/png;base64,'+this.screenData.screen_shot;
```

and the calculation that I'm doing fetch element-

```
getOffset(event){
      let x = event.pageX - event.target.offsetLeft;
      let y = event.pageY - event.target.offsetTop;
      let xRatio = this.screenData.imageWidth / document.getElementById('canvas').offsetWidth;
      let yRatio = this.screenData.imageHeight / document.getElementById('canvas').offsetHeight;
      x = Math.round(x * xRatio); //calculated: width of the screenshot 
      y = Math.round(y * yRatio);
    }
```

the height and width that I've set in the canvas is the problem I feel.

Comment: Can u please share your code I also need the same .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the bounding rectange for the canvas element for the offset.

Also, don't use pageX/pageY.  Those are not fully supported.

e.g.

```
const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
const mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
const mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;
```